# PHP Regexp on filename and number

Tags: php, regex

How to catch and filer the filename

**Input:**

```
news.jpg
news_1.png
asnews_2.gif
asnews_3.jpeg
aw_news_4.jpg
aw_news.gif
```

**Outout:**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => news
        [1] => news_1
        [2] => asnews_2
        [3] => asnews_3
        [4] => aw_news_4
        [5] => aw_news
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 3
        [4] => 4
        [5] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => news
        [1] => news
        [2] => asnews
        [3] => asnews
        [4] => aw_news
        [5] => aw_news
    )

)
```

I have tried in PHP using **preg_match_all** and **preg_replace_callback**, which I dont how to use correctly.

```
preg_match_all('/(?: _???_ (?:_([\d]+))?$/im', $fullname, $result);  // $fullname - string
```

This is a similar example - **/(?:(?:_([\d]+))?(.[^.]+))$/**. You can change this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = array (array (), array (), array ());

$dir = opendir ("/tmp");
while (($file = readdir ($dir)) !== false)
{
  if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;

  $matches = array ();
  preg_match ('/^(([^.]*?)(?:_([0-9]*))?)(?:\.|$)/', $file, $matches);

  $result [0][] = $matches [1];
  $result [1][] = $matches [3];
  $result [2][] = $matches [2];
}
closedir ($dir);

print_r ($result);
```

Output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => news
        [1] => news_1
        [2] => asnews_2
        [3] => asnews_3
        [4] => aw_news_4
        [5] => aw_news
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] =>
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 3
        [4] => 4
        [5] =>
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => news
        [1] => news
        [2] => asnews
        [3] => asnews
        [4] => aw_news
        [5] => aw_news
    )
)
```

Comment: Almost got it. But little wrong conclusion, for example, aw_news_4.jpg. See question (already edited). Thanks.

Comment: Everything turned out all right. But again failed - preg_replace_callback. See my second question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087406/php-regexp-on-filename-and-number-preg-replace-callback. You can write the answer. Thank you very much and waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try `explode` function in php.Explode the string contains filename.Use '.' as the explode delimeter and extraxt the exploded array to get the file name.

For reference about explode manual try this

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: If the file name has .(dot) explicitly, this will break the file name.

Comment: Doesnt matter..Take last occurence of '.' and split the string

Answer (score 0):

Use the [basename()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function to retrieve the file name without its extension.

- [`basename()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) — Returns filename component of path